# Twisted - Specifying the exact number of bytes coming in dataReceived

Tags: python, twisted

I am using Twisted to create a simple TCP server. With the Twisted Protocol, Is it ipossible to specific the exact number of bytes returned by *dataReceived*?

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint
from twisted.internet import reactor

class TestProtocol(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        print(id(self))
        self.transport.write('hello')

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print('connection lost called')

    def dataReceived(self, data):
                    # is it possible to specify size of "data"?
        print('data received called')

class TestFactory(Factory):
    protocol = TestProtocol

endpoint = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8007)
endpoint.listen(TestFactory())
reactor.run()
```

I ask this question because if I can control the number of bytes coming in, I can avoid dealing with partial protocol messages or multiple protocol messages coming in a single dataReceived callback.

I was able to achieve this with asynccore by specifying the exact number of bytes in the recv() method. It would be great to be able to do this in Twisted as well.

Thanks

... Alan

Answer (score 0):

Why not define a buffer and use that to grab messages of the size you want. LineReciever does something similar.

Something along the lines of:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint
from twisted.internet import reactor

class TestProtocol(Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__buffer = ""
        self.frame_size = 3 #FRAME SIZE HERE


    def connectionMade(self):
        print(id(self))
        self.transport.write('hello')

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print('connection lost called')

    def dataReceived(self, data):
                    # is it possible to specify size of "data"?
        print('data received called')
        self.__buffer = self.__buffer+data
        frame_size = self.frame_size
        while len(self.__buffer) >= frame_size:
            self.frame_received(self.__buffer[0:frame_size])
            self.__buffer=self.__buffer[frame_size:]

    def frame_received(self,data):
        print data


class TestFactory(Factory):
    protocol = TestProtocol

endpoint = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8007)
endpoint.listen(TestFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Your posted code isn't complete because it fails the case where multiple messages may come in dataReceived at once. Parsing streams is error proning, and would be nice to have something similar to Netty LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.

Comment: Good point. I think that case can easily be dealt with using a while loop though.

Comment: Modified the code to handle the longer message case with a loop. If you're concerned about the possibility of bugs then you might want to look more into the twisted library (or perhaps someone else will post a suggestion here :-) ) to see if there is something ready made that will do the job. Good luck.

Comment: A while loop is typical here. I have done this in C++ numerous time before. However, this pattern requires two unit test cases - stream underflow and overflow. And most people get it wrong the first try, including your post. If I can specify the read size, I can avoid this pattern and stop re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Just deal with the partial protocol messages.

Twisted provides numerous classes to help you do this [in the `twisted.protocols.basic` package](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.2.0/api/twisted.protocols.basic.html).  Normally one of those should just work for you; it's pretty unusual to have to implement your own custom framing protocol.

If you're designing your *own* protocol, you should probably just use twisted's built-in protocol construction kit, the [Asynchronous Messaging Protocol](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.2.0/api/twisted.protocols.amp.html). (Support for other langauges and frameworks available at [amp-protocol.net](http://amp-protocol.net).

Comment: The basic package didn't seem to meet my needs. I am implementing an existing protocol, and its header is a bit like IPv4 - very packed and informative.

Comment: Hmm. Would the `struct` module be sufficient to parse its header?